# R lapply on a function with three variables

Tags: r

I have a function with three variables

```
fcalc <- function(n1,n2,n3){

calc1 <- n1*5+n2*10-n3*2

)
```

I want to pass the values:
 1:2 to n1
 3:5 to n2
and 
6:9 to n3

However when I try

```
list1 <-lapply(1:2,3:5,6:9,fcalc)
liat1
```

I get an error.

eg when n1=1 and n2=3 and n3=6
the function would give

calc1 <- 1*5+3*10-6*2

23

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: What should happen in the second iteration when `n2 = 5`? What should `n1` be?

Comment: n1 loops from 1 to 2. n2 loops from 3 to 5, n3 loops from 6 to 9

Comment: so it should be a nested loop? And I wanted to refer to the third iteration, not the second

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: do you meant, df <- expand.grid(1:2,3:5,6:9), and you apply fcalc on every row of df?

Comment: `lapply` is a single loop (one variable varies), `f(x1), f(x2), f(x3), ...`. `Map` is the generalization to multiple variables---but it is in parallel, `f(x1, y1), f(x2, y2), f(x3, y3)`, etc., not every combination. If you want every combination, use a nested loop, or generate a matrix/data frame of the combos with `expand.grid` and loop over rows.

Comment: Thanks. expand.grid helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you actually want to do is to get calc1 for each combination of the values then this could be your solution:

```
fcalc <- function(x) {
  x[1]*5+x[2]*10-x[3]*2
}
(df <- expand.grid(x1=1:2,x2=3:5,x3=6:9))
(df$calc1 <- apply(df,1,fcalc))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
fcalc <- function(n1, n2, n3) n1 * 5 + n2 * 10  - n3 * 2
pmap_dbl(crossing(n1 = 1:2, n2 = 3:5, n3 = 6:9), fcalc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `outer()`:

```
fcalc <- function(x, y, z) {
 c(outer(outer(x * 5, y * 10, FUN = "+"), z * 2, FUN = "-"))
}

fcalc(1:2, 3:5, 6:9)

[1] 23 28 33 38 43 48 21 26 31 36 41 46 19 24 29 34 39 44 17 22 27 32 37 42
```